# Programmatically insert commerce stock failed

Tags: entities, database, commerce

I am using this code to insert the commerce stock but it fails some how:

```
$cp = commerce_product_new($product_type);
$cp->is_new = TRUE;
$cp->revision_id = NULL;
$cp->uid = 1;
$cp->status = 1;
$cp->created = $cp->changed = time();
$cp->sku = $product_sku;
$cp->title = $product_title;
$cp->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$cp->commerce_price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array(
   'amount' => $product_price,
   'currency_code' => 'GBP',
)));
$cp->commerce_stock[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 10;
commerce_product_save($cp);
```

I checked on the documentation using:

```
$cp->commerce_stock[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 10;
```

should do the trick, but strangely its not updating. Am I missing anything? All the rest is working except the stock.

thank you

Comment: Have you confirmed the field you are wanting to update is "commerce_stock"?

Comment: yes, its commerce_stock, I checked it, strangely the stock is not updating..

Comment: Have you enabled the commerce_ss module and enabled the stock field?

Comment: yes both are enabled and stock field are good, as I am able to do it via the UI and the stock is updated but not by this code..

Comment: In the above example, is the product being created at all and just the stock information is missing? Or does nothing get created?

Comment: @nvahalik, the product is created but the stock number is 0